# Prefetch files with C and stdlib

Tags: c, multithreading, file, mpi

For a numerical routine implemented in C I need to read data from files (ascii). The data is needed as input for the numerical computation and will in general be too large to fit it into the memory. Hence I need to prefetch it dynamically to some array to feed it into the routine (otherwise reading the file will be the botlenck in the computation). Is there an established/simple way to do this using stdlib, maybe posix threads or MPI? I am working with intels MPI library under Linux.

The routine `func`in the following pseudo-code represents the numerical core routine. It is called very frequently, say by a solver for ordinary differential equations. Each time `i` it is called with a random float value of `x[i-1]<x[i]<x[i-1]+D` with known value of `D`. So there is some early information about `x` which allows me to know approximately which data values from the file are needed in the next step.

```
read_file(x,data)
{
   /* code to search x-dependent data in file */
   data[i]=...;
}

func(x)
{

   read_file(x,&data);

   /* several data- and x-dependent operations */
   result= ...;

  return result;

}
```

While the block `/*  several data- and x-dependent operations */` (and some external code) is executed I can in principle prefetch the data needed in the next call of `func` from the file into a buffer array in parallel. On the next call I can search the information in the array instead of the file. I ask for the code needed to prefetch the data in parallel and the replacement for read_file (the part which communicates to the file reader which data will be needed in the next step). Ideally, if the `/*  several data- and x-dependent operations */` block needs about as much time as searching the file later would not take any extra time. If the code stays at it is the execution time will be about twice as long (neglecting the time needed for external opperations). Note that, if the block takes more time than the read, I can easily parallelize it. Something I cannot do with the present reader.

Comment: Why prefetching it? Wouldn't read on demand also do?

Comment: See my additional explanations above!

Comment: First of all I'd like to point you to angainor's answer. Secondly it might be interesting to know how much time your app actually spends reading the data needed for one calculation step and how long the latter runs. Knowing this will definitely help to decide whether it'll make sense to invest the time to implement the concurrently running data reader.

Comment: Unfortunately this is hard to say in general. It will depend a lot on the dimension of the data, its resolution in x, the time spent for the numerical block (which depends on both and also different quantities). So its hard to find 'typical' values. Note also that I can in principle parallelize the reader if it is realized as a parallel thread by splitting the data to different files for which I can have copies of the reader.

Answer (score 3):

First thing I would suggest you to do is to convert the ASCII file to a binary file (e.g., store native doubles as 8 bytes, not as an ASCII string, etc.). I have been struggling with a very much similar thing when running high-resolution FEM models. I was preparing a mesh using [triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html). Unfortunately, it only has ascii input/output and for large meshes reading the data took ages! really. I patched triangle to add support for binary io, and all the problems disappeared. You can use standard fread to get the data from files into allocated memory, and voilà! Sure, you have to store them in the file in a reasonable way, so that you can access/read contiguous chunks.

You should try to do that because parsing of the ASCII data, especially for floating point numbers is very expensive. If you still have problems, you might want to start a background thread/worker that would read in the data while the other thread(s) do the computations in the meantime. I would simply use pthreads for that on shared memory computers, leaving MPI to handle the cluster version of the code. Depends what you need.

If you want to go for the multithreaded IO, what you are looking for is a classic producer-consumer solution. There are tons of examples lying around, with simple implementations in any language, and using any threading library you like. Have a look at [this page discussing some classic examples](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~jcook/Tools/pthreads/examples.html) in concurrent computing using pthreads.

Comment: Thanks! I have been aware of the ascii issue. The question is pretty much one for the "thread/worker that would read in the data". I assume that it is not too difficult but I am new to threaded programming and I would prefere to avoid stepping into the pitfalls.  So an example would be really usefull for me.

Comment: @highsciguy oh, does it take so long to compute?;)